# ngStyle Problem with receiving colors from an object/model

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-template

I have designed a special shape with html/Css and I want to receive its color from a data service.

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color':'#0B0036'}"
```

when I use this code, everything works fine. but as soon as I try this:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color':'{{Card.lesson.color}}'}"  (with or without quote)
```

or

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color':'Card.lesson.color'}"
```

I either get errors or don't get any color at all.

what is the correct way to write that syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': Card.lesson.color }"
```

You are binding an *expression* into your template, not a string.

See [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) for more details